# batch processing of multiplication of a column vector and a row vector in mini-batch learning

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, parallel-processing, gradient-descent

In Matlab, I want to multiply a column vector **A**  with row vector **B**. The obtained result is a matrix. Now suppose I want to multiple **A<sub>1</sub>**, **A<sub>2</sub>**, ..., **A<sub>n</sub>** and **B<sub>1</sub>**, **B<sub>2</sub>**, ..., **B<sub>n</sub>** in batch. That is, I want to take advantage o the parallel processing capability of Matlab on matrix by somehow forming this problem into a matrix multiplication problem.  By the way, parfor does not work in my case.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to implement mini-batch learning in Matlab. Suppose there are n training examples in a mini-batch. When I try to backpropagate the error, my errors for all cases in a minibatch are n row vectors **B<sub>1</sub>**, **B<sub>2</sub>**, ..., **B<sub>n</sub>**. And the gradient corresponding to all n cases are n column vector **A<sub>1</sub>**, **A<sub>2</sub>**, ..., **A<sub>n</sub>**. I want to multiply them to obtain the incremental weights for all n cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a matrix `A` (resp. `B`) in which the columns are your `n` vectors **A1,A2,...,An** (resp. **B1,B2,...,Bn** ),

Your program would output `n` matrices. In order to vectorize this, you have to increase by 1 the dimensions of your matrices ( In this case 2-->3 dimensions matrices). The i-th "slice" of them at constant `z`  will be respectively your vectors `Ai` and `Bi`. Then, you can use `bsxfun` with the `@times` function handle :

```
n=size(A,2);
rA=reshape(A,[],1,n); % Flip A to 1st and third dimensions
rB=reshape(B,1,[],n);

% use bsxfun to compute the products
Out=bsxfun(@times, rA,rB);

% Now Out is a 3-d matrix where slices at constant z
% are the output matrices you want

% The trick here is that matrix multiplication
% of a column vector Ai with a row vector Bi is equal to elementwise
% multiplication of matrix [Ai Ai ... Ai] with matrix [Bi;Bi;...;Bi], 
 % and that's what the call to bsxfun does 
 % (see the part about "singleton expansion")
```

Comment: Excellent trick! Great answer. Thank you very much. One typo I noticed is that in Out=bsxfun(@times, A,B), aren't there rA and rB?

Comment: Was rA and rB indeed. Glad I could help